# Bootstrap Migration to 3.0 Pagination List Issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagination

As far as I could tell this question has not been asked anywhere else.

I have checked the bootstrap migration guide as well as bootply and cannot find anything regarding pagination lists. Basically, at the end of a table of search results I want something like:

<<|1|2|3|4|5>>

but at the moment, that is displaying vertically now instead of horizontally as pictured above.

Here is the main code snippet in question:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <format:paginationList pageResults="${searchResults}" modelName="participant" />    
</div>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to apply a custom class in css that added an "list-inline" style to the ul that contained the pagination. Applying this fix resolved the issue and made my pagination horizontal as it should be.